# Reading file contents by specifying file location within script tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

My requirement is that I have to read an XML file from the local folder(no web server here) then parse this xml and populate the html form fields.

I've tried the following approach:

```
<script type='text/xml' id='XMLData'>
 <category><cd><artist>mk</artist><id>12</id></cd></category>
</script>
<script>
  xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())),
      plans = xml.find('cd');


plans.each(function () {
   var artist= $(this).find('artist').text();
    $('#artist').val(artist);
});
</script>
<html>
  <input type="text" id="artist">ARTISt:</input>
 </html>
```

This works fine, but what I cannot specify the xml file content as shown above - I need to read the xml file content dynamically.

I thought of specifying the location of the file in the script tag as follows:

```
<script type='text/xml' id='XMLData' src="./xmlfile/cds.xml></script>
```

This is where I am stuck, I want to read the xml file contents from the src file.

How can I read the XML file / contents from the given source?